# Unix time to Human time in R

Tags: r, unix, datetime-conversion

My dataset follows such structure:

```
author, thread, created, converted
```

Created is in Unix time, converted is to be changed to `POSIXct` format. I have converted the data to subset using POSIXct` format:

```
data$converted <- as.POSIXct(data$created/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
```

However, the returned output is slightly off. For example, for the unix `timestamp` like this `1379017192658`, R returns human time `9/13/13 5:49:52`.

While the time in online converted (and using a formula in excel) returns a slightly different conversion of `9/12/13 8:19 PM`

What am I missing here?

Comment: thank you - of course! R converts to my timezone, while otherwise it is converted to GMT. if anybody sees and has a fast solution - would be grateful. Otherwise, will post my solution as figure out

Comment: I didn't know that there are time zones with half hour differences. You live you learn...

Comment: Thank you - this was an easy mistake - and adjusting a time zone solved: as.POSIXct(d/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")